# Timing type error with circleci after updating bundle

Tags: rspec, bundler, circleci

I don't know if it is related but this happened after updating the bundle version. It puts as an example `spec/requests/posts_spec.rb` but if I delete that file then goes to the one coming right after.

What could be the issue?

```
Error autodetecting timing type, falling back to weighting by name. Autodetect no matching filename or classname.  If file names are used, double check paths for absolute vs relative.
Example input file: "spec/requests/posts_spec.rb"
Example file from timings: ""
DEPRECATION WARNING: Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION is deprecated! Use Devise::Models::Authenticatable::UNSAFE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SERIALIZATION instead. (called from block (2 levels) in require at /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION is deprecated! Use Devise::Models::Authenticatable::UNSAFE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SERIALIZATION instead. (called from block (2 levels) in require at /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60)
No examples found.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```